# Laptop model number breakdown

Tags: laptop

I'm in the market for a new laptop, and although i've been working in IT for the last 10 years, i've never bought one for myself, as i prefer working on desktop machines, or i have always been provided a notebook by my employer.
It's clear that on a desktop machine i can freely choose components (keyboard, screen, ram, etc.), while with notebooks you're stuck with whatever the manufacturer thinks are good combinations of hardware, therefore it's being very hard to pinpoint the exact machine i want to buy.
I will refer here to a specific make/model for the sake of example, not recommendation.

Say i want to buy a notebook from the ASUS TUF gaming line.
The question is: how can i figure out the exact combination of characters that makes up the Part Number that has the stuff i want in it?

So far i have been able to identify the following numbers/letters: consider P/N FX506IV-HN228T, it can be broken down as follows:
FX - series
506/706 - 15.6" or 17.3" display (previous models were 505/705)
IV/IU - RTX2060 or GTX1660Ti graphics card (previous models were DV/DU, and DT for GTX1650)
The last part i have seen changing wildly (HN228T, AL032T, AS76, BQ138, H7121T), and so far i could not match a single digit to a specific hardware change, these include monitor refresh rate, SSD size, battery capacity.

I'm used to work with electronic datsheets, so let's take [this one](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2065c-2.pdf?ts=1596188211095&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS2065C-2) as example: if i go to the manufacturer's website, i can find all the specific versions differentiated, as i summed up in this picture
[TI TPS20xx P/N differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke9mX.png)

So far i was not able to find such a detailed roundup on any notebook manufacturer's website; i understand that not all combinations are going to be available in every region, as usually availability is targeted on models which are more likely to sell in a specific region.
I also think that tinkering with part numbers is something that would confuse the genral public, while only appealing to power users who would care about this stuff.

Does any notebook manufacturer provide such a thing? And if no, what reasons could they possibly have for not doing this?

Comment: “Does any notebook manufacturer provide such a thing? And if no, what reasons could they possibly have for not doing this?” Well why would they? How many laptop manufacturers sell laptops to the public based on nothing but part numbers? They can use whatever part numbers they want whether it follows a logical convention or not. That’s why the manufacture provides list of specifications and the part number is not particularly prominent. What you really want is a searchable database containing models from multiple manufacturers. e.g. https://www.notebookcheck.net/Laptop_Search.8223.0.html

Comment: @James P if i'm gonna buy the MSI G65, or the ASUS TUF A15, that covers a whole spectrum of specs: in my opinion, if the manufacturer would list the model number, one could compare it to the one found on the e-shop or at the retailer's to confirm it's the same version (exact hw components); if the downvote is for not linking to notebookcheck.net's search engine, it's my fault for not making it clear that that's exacty what i've used for my research

Comment: I didn’t down vote you but I still don’t understand the problem. I think you would probably waste more time trying to decipher the manufacturer numbering schemes than you would by manually checking specs in every major online retailer

Comment: The notebookcheck DB does cover model variants and show the full codes. Obviously it won’t cover everything and mainly covers those sold in Europe

Comment: @James P: i'm beginning to see now my view is, indeed, distorted, mostly by my field of specialization; the point was not to reverse-decode the part numbers, but instead to find a list of them, already laid down by the manufacturer, from which i could select one and order, much like i would do with an integrated circuit. Attie's answer is pretty spot-on, with regard to this specific point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i figure out the exact combination of characters that makes up the Part Number that has the stuff i want in it?

You probably can't, and the construction of part numbers is very manufacturer specific.

To make this worse, you'll sometimes even find that even the "*specific part number*" for a particular model still isn't precise enough - you may find it being sold in a number of different places, with slightly different specs.

> Does any notebook manufacturer provide such a thing?

I'm not aware of any, but the bigger / corporate facing manufacturers and models may have part numbers that break down like this.

> And if no, what reasons could they possibly have for not doing this?

To be honest, a lot of the time it's just not necessary. Things like screen size and battery capacity will often be an intrinsic spec that is the same across an entire model range, regardless of the processor or other components.

Other more flexible things like the processor / RAM / storage / GPU / resolution / touchscreen / etc... will often come as a pre-ordained set of specifications, and as such it's likely that a single character in the part number could represent the entire range of options the customer has. In some ways, you're lucky if they expand on this at all!

---

It can be frustrating that the part number doesn't contain the complete decodable set of specs, but even if it did, there is no standard or governing body, so trying to compare between manufacturers isn't going to work out because they'll all be dfferent.

Your best bet is to list out the specs you're interested in, compare them directly, and purchase the laptop from the vendor that gave you the specs (or direct from the manufacturer).

Comment: I can clearly see that across manufacturers would be impossible; i thought it would have been the most efficient way to determine what to look for in shops, within the manufacturer's own lineup, therefore it baffled me when i wasn't able to find it; i thought my google-fu was the issue, but perhaps i'm just rusted on conventions that only pertain within my workspace. Either that, or i'm an old person that rants about every thing made differently from what i see fit...
Great answer, though :)

Comment: "_most efficient way to determine what to look for in shops_" - sadly (as I hope I covered in my answer) using the most precise model number available can still result in different specs depending on the vendor... If you work in the industrial / electronics / manufacturing spaces, then part numbers are indeed often very prescriptive and break down explicitly. In the consumer world, this isn't really how it works.